# Invoke SOAP API using StreamSets on Cloudera

Tags: soap, cloudera, streamsets

What is the way to invoke the SOAP API on streamsets and how to pass the WSDL to it? What are the boxes needed to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTTP Client stage and set the `SOAPAction` header with the target method. You then pass the SOAP request as the body of a POST, using Expression Language to insert record field values into the XML.